# what is the name of this curve

Tags: frequency-response, z-transform

I was drawing a high pass filter response ,in a polar coordinates, the function is `(z+1)/z` and then it is `2+2*cos(w)`
the plot is [image: here]
What is the name of this plot, is it a frequency response or impulse response or some thing else.

and how to distinguish it from other curves names.

Comment: Looks like a [cardioid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cardioid.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is called a cardioid pattern. (cardioid because it looks vaguely heart-shaped)

You've shown us a polar frequency magnitude plot with the frequency given in radians. You'll notice by going counter-clockwise around the unit circle that low frequencies are attenuated while the higher frequencies are passed through.

Comment: So can I mention it like this: "as we see in the frequency polar plot with the frequency given in radians" or just "frequency polar plot" or "frequency response polar plot" or what?

Comment: The curve is a "frequency magnitude plot". The word "polar" is an adjective, describing what kind of plot.  I suggest you use, "polar frequency magnitude plot."